# Can "front" be used as a adverb like "back"?

Tags: grammar

To give a example, "David is as far back the boundary as John is far front".

I never heard of such use of the word "front".

Maybe, I should say: "David is as far back the boundary as John is **in front of it**.

Comment: The latter is more idiomatically correct,  at least....

Comment: I never heard such use of the word *back* either.    I'd say "David is as far behind the boundary as John is in front of it" or "David is as far back from the boundary as John is in front of it" or even "David is as far inside the boundary as John is outside it".

Comment: Then shall I delete this?

Comment: Generally you'd use "forward", not "front", in such contexts.

Comment: What about usages such as "walk back" and "face front"?  Wouldn't back and front be adverbs in such sentences?  For example, "The children decided to walk back to their home".

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/front), **front** can only be used as an adverb if preceded by in.

> *adverb*
>
> **in ˈfront**
>
> in a position that is further forward than somebody/something but not
>   very far away
>
> *Their house is the one with the big garden in front.*
>
> in first place in a race or competition
>
> *The blue team is currently in front with a lead of six points.*

Answer (score 0):

> David is as far back the boundary

This is incorrect grammar. You must say:

> David is as far back **from** the boundary

Comment: Correct though it may be, this answer makes no attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the sample sentence "David is as far back the boundary as John is as far front" might also be expressed as follows:

> David is as far ***behind*** the boundary as John is as far ***ahead*** of it.

I realize this completely removes the word "front" from the original question. I mention it only because *front* and *back* in the example sound odd without prepositions.